# How to delete row in listview MVVM?

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm

I have 1 list. Each row of the list will have a delete button. I want to delete that line when I click that button and must use mvvm.

```
<ListView x:Name="ListViewRoutePlan" SelectedIndex="0" ItemsSource="{Binding RoutePlanResource}" Style="{StaticResource MaterialDesignListView}">
                    <ListView.View>
                        <GridView>
                            <GridViewColumn DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource FindAncestor, AncestorType={x:Type ListViewItem}},Converter={StaticResource IndexConverter}}" Header="STT" />
                            <GridViewColumn DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding Prioritize}" Header="Prioritize" />
                            <GridViewColumn DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding PlanStatus}" Header="Plan Status" />
                            <GridViewColumn DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding Note}" Header="Note" />
                            <GridViewColumn Header="Delete" >
                                <GridViewColumn.CellTemplate>
                                    <DataTemplate>
                                        <Button Command="{Binding ElementName=ListViewRoutePlan,Path=DataContext.RemoveSubjectCommand}" CommandParameter="{Binding ElementName=ListViewRoutePlan}" Background="{x:Null}" BorderBrush="{x:Null}" Margin="0,-5,0,0" HorizontalAlignment="Left">
                                            <materialDesign:PackIcon Kind="Delete" Margin="-5,0,0,0" Foreground="Black" Width="20" Height="20" />
                                        </Button>
                                    </DataTemplate>
                                </GridViewColumn.CellTemplate>
                            </GridViewColumn>
                        </GridView>
                    </ListView.View>
```

**view model**

I have run it here but I do not know how to write processing code to delete

```
  public class viewmodel : BaseViewModel
{
    public ICommand RemoveSubjectCommand { get; set; }
    public viewmodel()
    {
        RemoveSubjectCommand = new RelayCommand<ListView>((p) => { return true; }, (OnEdit));
    }
    private void OnEdit(ListView lsv)
    {

    }
}
```

Comment: Where is property RoutePlanResource defined?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The button command parameter should be the current item bound to the cell

```
CommandParameter="{Binding}"
```

And the command should be updated accordingly to remove the selected item from the collection

```
public class viewmodel : BaseViewModel {

    public viewmodel() {

        RemoveSubjectCommand = new RelayCommand<MyItemModel>((p) => { return true; }, (OnRemoveSubject));

        //assuming RoutePlanResource initialized and populated
    }

    public ObservableCollection<MyItemModel> RoutePlanResource {
        //assuming boilerplate getter and setter with notification
    }

    public ICommand RemoveSubjectCommand { get; set; }

    private void OnRemoveSubject(MyItemModel item) {
        RoutePlanResource.Remove(item);

        //...
    }
}
```

Comment: thanks. I still can not click on the button to delete.I have to choose a line before I can delete it.

Comment: @DevilNight yes I would expect that since an item has to be selected to be deleted. Then try `CommandParameter="{Binding}"` instead.

Comment: woa. thank you. Why does it work when editing is CommandParameter = "{Binding}"? you can explain? @Nkosi

Comment: `{Binding}` in this case mean bind to what ever object is the data context of the current element.

Comment: @DevilNight read up this from docs https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/wpf/advanced/binding-markup-extension